# How can I use ModelChoiceField with Filter in Django 1.11?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models related, I wanna show them with a multiplechoicefield from django.forms but also I wanna that one model had assigned depends on the multiplechoicefield of the related model.

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models....()
    ....

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    name = models....()
    model = models.ForeignKey()
```

In my form I have:

```
class ModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = forms.MultipleChoiceField(queryset = model.objects.all())
    other_model = forms.MultipleChoiceField(queryset = 
                             other_model.objects.all())
```

But I wanna do that other_model MultipleChoiceField show me objects only related with model related, how can I do that through queryset filter, or another way to do.

Comment: isn't it what foreign key does ?

Comment: what do you mean? inside the var `queryset` you can add whatever you want, for example `other_model.objects.filter(model=model.objects.get(pk=1))`